# IN operator with a very large list is too slow in SQL Server. What should I use instead?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a complex SQL query where the `IN` statement could contain over 50,000 ids. The query timeouts after 20-30 seconds and the only way to resolve this issue is to change the query to return the results hopefully in a no more than 1-2 seconds. Increasing the timeout is NOT an option.

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
) 

CREATE TABLE Feature
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [TagId] [INT] NOT NULL,
)
```

`Feature` table `ItemId` column is a non unique, non clustered index as well.

Select script:

```
SELECT i.Name
FROM Items i
INNER JOIN Feature f ON i.Id = f.ItemId
WHERE f.TagId IN (123, 234, 456, .....)
```

Even if the `Items` table have 3-400,000 records and the `IN` operator list has around 80,000 in the list, it will timeout.

I must improve the performance dramatically

Comment: What determines the values supplied to the IN clause?

Comment: Can you store those values in a (temp) table and join to it?

Comment: Show the full definitions, not just basic ones and then allusions to the indexes.

Comment: If you have values that are being used that can't be retrieved from the database using a proper join then you could use a [Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters). There might be other alternatives but it would help if you answered my initial question on **what determines the values, where are the values coming from**, as that can better direct you to how to construct a good solution.

Comment: Igor the values within the IN clause are coming from another text search. Features are loaded into memory and using `Contains("test")` it will return an id list from the feature table which will be used in this query

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `Contains("test")`, is that application code or do you mean something in Sql Server like FTS? If you meant these values are coming from the application side then the best solution might be to use a TVP or temp table or json. I ordered these options based on my personal preference.

Comment: It is `C#` `Linq`. That is the fastest way to get the list of ids. There is no way to produce this list from the `DB` any faster. It is equals to `WHERE TagName LIKE '%test%'`

Comment: But you are saying this list of IDS originates from the same database that you are then executing the query for? So your steps are 1 - some input, 2 - query big list of ids, 3 - query db for additional data using big list of ids as input. Is that about right?

Comment: ^-- assuming this is correct then can we take a step back and focus on step 2 and see if we can combine that with step 3? That would make the most sense. The question then becomes why split these up? To better answer that it would be most helpful to include the query you were using for that step and then we can figure out how to combine the 2.

Comment: Step 1 and 2 is done already the best possible way I think. Or do you know a way to run a query against a `DB` for a free text search with 2-400,000 records? Because my app does this probably in less than a second. The only question is how to get step 3 done in no more than a few seconds

Comment: Its no the fact that you can speed up step 1/2 but that you can use those results as a part of step 3 all in the same query. You can probably omit the part where you retrieve these IDS for use in part 3 and instead run the whole thing as 1 query. It would be easier to help if you could include some sort of [mcve] for the query that is returning these IDs that you currently run on its own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key thing here is to get the IDS out of the query text SQL.  You can pass the IDS in JSON or XML, or a Table-Valued Parameter, or bulk load a temp table.  All will be much faster.

EG this

```
use AdventureWorks2017
set nocount on
dbcc freeproccache
go

declare @ids varchar(max) = ( select STRING_AGG(cast(salesorderid as varchar(max)),',') from sales.SalesOrderHeader )

select @ids 

select count(*)
from 
sales.SalesOrderheader

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
select * 
from sales.salesorderheader
where SalesOrderID in (' + @ids + ')'

print '---------IN list---------'
set statistics time on
exec (@sql)
set statistics time off
print '---------IN list---------'



print '---------JSON array---------'
set statistics time on
select * 
from sales.salesorderheader
where SalesOrderID in ( select value from openjson('[' + @ids + ']') )
set statistics time off
print '---------JSON array---------'
```

outputs

```
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
---------IN list---------
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 11781 ms, elapsed time = 12115 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 657 ms,  elapsed time = 1453 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 12438 ms,  elapsed time = 13569 ms.
---------IN list---------
---------JSON array---------

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 656 ms,  elapsed time = 984 ms.
---------JSON array---------
```

To use this method from C# is super-simple.  Just serialize an array or list into a string, and pass it in a SqlParameter.  EG:

```
var con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;database=adventureworks2017;integrated security=true");
con.Open();

var ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 50_000).ToList();

var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select * from sales.SalesOrderHeader where salesorderid in (select value from openjson(@pIds))";
var pIds = cmd.Parameters.Add("@pIds", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

pIds.Value = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ids);

using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            //do whatever
            Console.Write(".");
        }
}
```

Comment: David, I love the way you think and you obviously think it through. However there is one big issue. I have text search implemented which in done in `C#` using `Linq Contains()` from a list in memory! This list contains 2-400,000 items. This search is done very quickly, but if I would do this is `MSSQL` just this text search would kill the whole query, because it would be so slow.  `LIKE '%test%' is not exaclty fast

Comment: how would you do the `Tabel-Valued Parameter` or the bulk load temp table? I dont know how to do that

Comment: Honestly, I would just use a JSON array if you can.  It's super-easy to generate from C# using a JSON serializer of a 'List<int>' or 'int[]'.  Then just pass it using a SqlParameter and a query like `select ... from .... where id in (select value from openjson(@listParam))`.

Comment: The following `SQL IN` clause was generated 
`ct.TagId IN (SELECT VALURE FROM openjson(@idParamList))`
Passing the `Json` param as within the `SqlAdapter` command.Parameters, but it is not picking up the `Json` param

Comment: Unbelieveable David. Well DONE! It was just a typo on my end and it the `JSON` parameter works perfectly. It returns the result in about 1-1.5 seconds! Unfortunately, I cannot catch the query string for some reason in `SQL Profiler`, but who cares, it is lightning quick. I would love to work with you and learn a lot more from you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the ids into a temporary table and then use it inside the join, also an index on the temp table may help

Comment: Or pass the IDs in a Table-Valued Parameter, or a JSON array, or an XML document.

Comment: You should show some example code -- this will make your answer clearer

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft -- I don't think those will be faster if the problem is parsing the IN list.

Comment: It's not typically parsing the IN list per-se that's the problem.  It's parsing and compiling the huge query.  And both of these get the data out of the query body.

Comment: See my supplemental answer for a comparison of the IN list vs passing the delimited string as a single parameter and parsing it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
--develop your list for the IN operator    
with cte1 as
(
select tagId
from feature
where ...
),
-- limit your feature table to tagid that you want to see
cte2 as
(
select tagid
from feature a
inner join cte1 b
on a.tagid = b.tagid
)
SELECT i.Name
FROM Items i
inner join cte2 b
on i.tagid = b.tagid
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using an EXISTS could be faster.
Since the query doesn't seem to need fields from the Feature table.

```
SELECT i.Name
FROM Items i
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Feature f
    WHERE f.TagId IN (123,234,456,.....)
      AND f.ItemId = i.id
);
```

If that doesn't work, some other ideas.
 - Load the list of Tagid's into a new table (temporary?) with a primary key on Tagid.  Then in the query join to that table instead of using IN.
-  Add a non-unique index on Feature.TagId

Comment: Non-unique index is already added on the column and unfortunately `EXISTS` would not make that big of a difference